# How to make git notes to pull automatically for everyone who clones repo?

Tags: git, githooks, git-notes

Is it possible at all?

I've read in documentation that you can configure it in your local `.git/config`
like:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

But it is local settings and as i understand i can't push it to i.e. github or bitbucket. Is it possible to force everyone to pull notes?

Comment: What is the documentation saying that?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch oops it was blog post https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/08/25/notes.html

Comment: git and force everyone to do something sounds strange

Comment: @Ôrel we just want so everyone saw git notes in `git log` because notes contain corresponding revision number when project used Subversion. It is tedious for everyone who wants to find commit by svn revision number to search for `git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*` and execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to ***force*** everyone to pull notes?

(emphasis mine) No.

> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

This is the normal setting.  You need to *add* a setting to copy notes references.  There are many possible ways to do that, e.g., if you never make your own notes:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits
```

If you *do* make your own notes, you will want something fancier, e.g.:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/origin/commits
```

and then manipulate the `core.notesRef` setting and/or use `--notes=` when running `git log`.

Everyone who *wants* the notes, however, must specifically *ask* for the notes, by adding an extra `fetch` line to their configurations.